# Blender freezes every few seconds in specific scene

Tags: performance

Originally problem appeared on Blender 2.93, but today I switched to 3 exactly hoping that there all will be fine, but, the problem is still here.

I have been experimenting with creating city terrains, so I made a simple road with some area around it. First, Blender worked as normal, but at some point it started to freeze every few seconds (about 10).

It seems, that that behavior started after I hugely scaled up uv for an large area around the road, but the problem is still here even after resetting uv.

I tried to disable autosave, I, as wrote above, updated Blender, but it didn't help. Currently I am going to update graphical card drivers, but not sure that it is solution.

[image]

Comment: I tried your file, I have tried many different things but I didn't experience any problem at all. What hw are you using? Is it enough for minimum requirements?

Comment: @MikoCG I am using Surface Go 2, it has low hardware, but it is weird, because this scene seems to be pretty light. I have been working earlier with more complex models with bigger amount of vertices, 8k textures and there was no such problem… Today I will try to update drivers, and if it will not solve the problem, then I don’t know

Comment: I am not really sure because I cannot replicate your problem with my hardware, try those drivers if anything will happen or try different version of blender as well

Comment: @MikoCG I remembered one more detail. From this  https://youtu.be/-VgtSL5ZpYc video I dowloaded a blend file with nodes and applied one of them to randomly rotate tiled texture of mud near the road. And approximately after that it started freezing (even after I disabled the node)

Comment: I remember that, I used it for my whole use of 2.8x blender and it never caused any problem even on my older PC... and I just tried it on 3.0 just in case and still works

Comment: @MikoCG but I checked a Shading and that node is completely removed (seems to be). What I notice more - seems that freezes are not happen in object mode for solid (without textures) as for material preview shading mode. Seems that it happens only in edit mode, and seems, when I select edges/faces

Comment: @MikoCG, well, seems that driver update solved the problem

Comment: @MikoCG, wait, no, drivers didn't fix that, but I noticed that I actually did not removed that custom node, because first I was looking on asphalt material, and node was on mud material. And now, after node removing, seems, that the problem is gone